# JuliaLang: converting STDIN to string

Tags: string, julia

I'm trying to read terminal input from juliabox. The problem is, the only way it accepts input is if I put the answer between quotes. In my case, I have to put "yes" or "no" to get the correct behavior.

```
response = readline()
 if response == "yes"
```

is there any way I can convert the input to a String to eliminate the need for the quotes?

Comment: the quotes in the code are not part of the string `yes`. for example, try, `println("yes")` and note the result is quote free.

Comment: If you put `response = readline()` and enter some text, what is the type of the resulting object? (Use `typeof`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most clear to leave it as "yes" in your example. The " " characters create the string type.

```
> typeof("yes")
ASCIIString
```

Alternatively, you can store the string and compare against it:

```
yes_str = "yes"
no_str = "no"
if response == yes_str
  # yes stuff
end
```

or a neat idea, check for multiple responses:

```
yes_strs = ["yes", "y", "yeah", "sure", "ok", "ya", "positive", "affirmative", "pos"]
no_strs = ["no", "n", "nah", "nope", "na", "negative", "negatory", "neg"]

# Convert to lower case for matching
response = lowercase(readline()) 

if response in yes_strs
  # yes stuff
elseif response in no_strs
  # no stuff
else
  println("I don't understand, give me a yes or no.")
  # other stuff
end
```